# Responsive website images the same height

Tags: responsive-design

I am trying to figure out how to make vertical and horizontal images at the same height. The height I need by vertical image. any ideas..

[image]

I was thinking to make the same height, but when I resize it shows like above...

```
css: max-height: 375px!important;
```

Update:

http://jsfiddle.net/LG2B8/

Comment: Have you tried: `height: 375px` ? It would be great if you could provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in which you reproduce the problem.

Comment: I cant, because there is slider script...

Comment: I putted demo, to show what is the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

use `min-height` for horizontal image

```
min-height: height of vertical image;
```

Answer (score 0):

as mention above, just give

> css: height: 375px!important;
>
> or
>
> css: height: 4%0!important;    //give in percent which is good for responsive ui

Some basic rule is

- Height - apply when you need / know proper height
- Max-height - apply when you want to restrict image height when exceed, this is good to used for images, you can also use for all other content too.
- Min -height - apply when you want to minimum height should be, this is used for div/table/tr/td for responsive ui

I rectify and only change in css. just remove everything and add this. I added width for understand.

> img
>
> {
>
> display: inline-block;
>
> height: 300px;
> width:200px;
> }

**img is html tag and all images will work as per "img" css attributes**

Comment: The percentage height is not working at all.., when I do static size like 375px and when I am resizing it resize only height but not width...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

Html:

```
<div class="w">
    <div class="img"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/4OAz0Cf.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="img o"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/EJsmCmT.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.w {
    display: table-row;
}

.img{
    width: 50%;
 display: table-cell;
}
.img img{
    min-height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
}
.img.o img {
    width: 100%;

}
```

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LG2B8/11/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for solution, but width is not resizing ... it only height.. maybe is it possible to make with overflow:hidden ?